# MySQL ODBC with Microsoft Excel 2007 Crash

Tags: mysql, excel, odbc

Trying to access certain tables/views using Excel causes the executing program, "Microsoft Query", to crash. "Ordinary" tables with only one primary key can be found and exported without any problems.

The table that can't be imported contains two columns which both are primary key and both are foreign keys. One of the views consists of a pair of inner joins and the other view is a grouped table (SUM() and GROUP BY). The table and these two views seem to crash the "Microsoft Query". Any idea of how to solve this?

EDIT:
The table looks somewhat like this:

```
CREATE TABLE AccountHolder
(
  Account BIGINT(10),
  Customer INT,
  PRIMARY KEY(Account, Customer),
  CONSTRAINT FKAccountHolderAccount
    FOREIGN KEY AccountHolder (Account)
    REFERENCES Account (AccountNumber),
  CONSTRAINT FKAccountHolderCustomer
    FOREIGN KEY AccountHolder (Customer)
    REFERENCES Customer (ID)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: How big are the tables?  It might be a lot of data for Excel to go get. Also, can we see the query by any chance?

Comment: The tables it's trying to get consists of roughly 20 rows with two columns, nothing that Excel should have any problem to get.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems.  When I clicked on the minus sign before the table name, Microsoft Query instantly crashed.

I performed some tests and after some trial and error, it seems that one of the problem was the length of the table name.  The table name exceeding 18 characters long made Microsoft Query crashes.

The workaround was to create a view with a name containing 18 characters or less.  I tried again and was able to view the table columns, select them and import them in Excel.

I double checked with a huge table with name having 18 or less character, containing 3M records and composed 147 columns and tried to retrieve the data.  I was able to select all the columns and to set some criterias, but Microsoft Query crashed again.  I thought at the moment that maybe the column name should comply to the same rule and it doesn't.

I created another view over the problematic table with the same column name and tried to retrieve the exact same records and it worked...  I am puzzled, but at least, it works.

Hope this will be helpful in some way.